# pandas: assign value based on equivalent value in another row with lookup

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    { "state": "CA", region="West", "total" 2, "week": 10 },
    { "state": "UT", region="Midwest", "total" 7, "week": 10 },
    { "state": "CA", region="CA", "total" 14, "week": 11 },
    { "state": "UT", region="UT", "total" 18, "week": 11 },
    { "state": "CA", region="West", "total" 21, "week": 12 },
    { "state": "UT", region="Midwest", "total" 30, "week": 12 }
])
```

(My real dataset has all the states in!)

All the `region` values for rows with `week` set to `11` have been set wrongly, so I would like to replace them with the value for the same state in week 10.

I tried this:

```
df[df.week == 11].region = df[df.week == 10].region
```

But it's reliant on the rows being in the same order, which they might not be. Is there a way I can do this while matching on state name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your states have weeks 10 and 11, you can sort and use `loc` as a label accessor to set new values once you have sorted your frame accordingly. Also I fixed the dictionary values for your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    { "state": "CA", "region":"West", "total" :2, "week": 10 },
    { "state": "UT", "region":"Midwest", "total": 7, "week": 10 },
    { "state": "CA", "region":"CA", "total" :14, "week": 11 },
    { "state": "UT", "region":"UT", "total" :18, "week": 11 },
    { "state": "CA", "region":"West", "total": 21, "week": 12 },
    { "state": "UT", "region":"Midwest", "total" :30, "week": 12 }
]).sort_values(by = ['state','week'])

df.loc[df['week'] == 11, 'region'] = df.loc[df['week'] == 10, 'region'].to_numpy()

df

>>
    state   region  total   week
0   CA  West    2   10
2   CA  West    14  11
4   CA  West    21  12
1   UT  Midwest 7   10
3   UT  Midwest 18  11
5   UT  Midwest 30  12
```

Answer (score 1):

the code to create your dataframe was messed up, so I couldn't test the following, but you can:

1. merge a subset of the dataframe back onto itself with the defined criteria merging on state and week (order does not matter since you are using a merge)
2. use `np.where()` to update the relevant values using the new `region_x` column to updated `region` where appropriate
3. then, you can just drop `region_x`

---

```
df = df.merge(df.loc[df['week'] == 11, ['state','region','week']].replace(10,11),
             how='left',
             on=['state', 'week'], suffixes=('', '_x'))
df['region'] = np.where(df['region'] == 11, df['region_x'], df['region'])
df = df.drop('region_x', axis=1)
```

---

If you don't mind sorting your dataframe you could also use `ffill()`. Make sure your 'region' column doesn't already have `NaN` values though. In case it does, I included this line of code: `df['region'] = df['region'].replace(np.nan, 'Unknown')` so that unintended `NaN` values aren't forward -filled unintentionally, but perhaps you don't need that line of code:

```
df = df.sort_values(['state', 'week'])
df['region'] = df['region'].replace(np.nan, 'N/A') #optional
df['region'] = np.where(df['week'] == 11, np.nan, df['region'])
df['region'] = df['region'].ffill()
```